# Conditional statement in bash

Tags: bash

```
x=23; y=223; [[ $x < $y ]] &&
echo yes || echo no;
```

Can someone explain me why am i getting answer as no instead of yes. I am new to bash. I would appreciate if someone could explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-lt` to compare numeric comparison:

```
x=23; y=223; [[ $x -lt $y ]] && echo yes || echo no;
yes
```

`<` or `>` or `==` operators do string comparison where `23` is * lexicographically* not grater that `223` hence giving `no` output.

Or better `((...))` arithmetic evaluator in BASH:

```
x=23; y=223; (( x < y )) && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

Comment: May i know why does "<" give a different result ? or can we say that it is illegal to use '<' instead of '-lt'

Comment: `<` does a string comparison where `23` is indeed greater than `223` lexicographically.

Comment: gotcha that's what i was looking for